# Selenium Scripts are getting invoked by Maven without my intention

Tags: selenium-webdriver, maven-2, testng, jenkins-plugins

I'm new to Selenium-Maven-Jenkins Integration. Scripts are automatically invoking in the machine without my intention and I'm not sure if this is possible due to any wrong configuration between Maven and Jenkins.  I have given below the source POM XML`enter code here and let me know if this is due to any issue with my maven configurations. I want to mention one more thing, that I recently took the copy of my work space and saved with different project name and I'm not sure if that could be the reason.

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Automation_Script</groupId>
  <artifactId>Automation_Script</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
        
        
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.18.1</version>
<configuration>
<suiteXmlFiles>
<!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
<suiteXmlFile>VoyaDigitalApps.xml</suiteXmlFile>

</suiteXmlFiles>
<configuration>
               <skipTests>false</skipTests>
               <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
              <forkCount>0</forkCount>
             <rerunFailingTestsCount>1</rerunFailingTestsCount>
           </configuration>
           </configuration>
     </plugin>  
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>1.41</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.1</version>
   </dependency>
   
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.16</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you clarify? What do you mean that the scripts are invoking without your intention?

Comment: Selenium scripts are running automatically. Invoking the browser and it is started running as per the test suite .I haven't initiated the scripts using eclipse or from Jenkins.

Comment: Perhaps the Jenkins job is configured (either by polling or a webhook) to run a build and tests after each commit?!

Answer (score 0):

yes looks jenkins job is scheduled.
However if you have access rights to check the configuration then use below step to change/remove the auto trigger of the job.

In jenkins, select that project/job , select Configure and look for Build Triggers - Build periodically (uncheck it/or edit schedule to change the run frequency)